# error using IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>> in discord bot

Tags: c#, discord

i have this code line

```
if (channel.GetUsersAsync().Contains(Program.kami.CurrentUser as IGuildUser))
do something;
```

it writes an exception which says IAsyncEnumerable> doesnt contain the definition of contains 
and i dont know what to do

```
[Command("join", RunMode=RunMode.Async), Summary("joins voice channel")]
public async Task joinvoice([Remainder, Summary("The text to echo")] string searchP="")
{

    IVoiceChannel channel = (CommandHandler.Last as IGuildUser).VoiceChannel;

    if (channel == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("u have to be in a channel first");
        return;

    }
    string choice = "";
    VideoSearch SearchRisolts = new VideoSearch();
    if (searchP != "")
    {
        if (searchP.Contains("https://"))
            choice = searchP;
        else
        {
            List<VideoInformation> video = SearchRisolts.SearchQuery(searchP, 1);
            await ReplyAsync("* " + video[0].Title + "\n\n* " + video[1].Title + "\n\n* " + video[2].Title);
            //choice = video[int.Parse() - 1].Url;
        }
        this.Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(1).First();
    }
    IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<IUser>> x = channel.GetUsersAsync();
    if ((await channel.GetUsersAsync()).Contains(Program.kami.CurrentUser as IGuildUser))
    var audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync();
    await SendAsync(audioClient,choice);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to await a GetUserAsync operations

```
(await channel.GetUsersAsync()).Contains(....)
```

Be sure that your method is async.

Comment: the method is async task. and i tried to place await like you did but it doesnt work and it writes that doesnt contain a definition of get awaiter

Comment: @BeniBlinches look at the parentheses around `GetUsersAsync`.

Comment: i did as he suggested me i stil cant find the problem